# All instances are not running in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-app-service-plans, event-processor-host

I am using Azure App Service which hosts application that reads data from Event hub using `EventProcessorHost`. I have allocated 6 instances(Manual Scaling) to run. I checked the Metrics(**CPU Time**) in App Service and found only 5 instances are running.

I am getting different instances count for different metrics.
**Data In** metrics shows 6 instances while **CPU Time** metrics shows 5 instances. I am confused. Please suggest.

[image]
[image]
Regards,
Amit Agrawal

Comment: Do you have *always on* enabled?

Comment: How many partitions does the Event Hub that you're reading from have?  Since the processor instances don't guarantee a fair split of the work (though they do their best to achieve it), it is possible that one of your instances simply doesn't have enough work and is spending a large portion of its time idle.

Comment: @JesseSquire - Event Hub has 32 partitions

Comment: @AlexAIT - What is Always on enabled feature ?

Comment: "Always On: Keep the app loaded even when there's no traffic. It's required for continuous WebJobs or for WebJobs that are triggered using a CRON expression." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common

Comment: @AlexAIT- Yes, Always on is enabled.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the processor logs on that instance to see the operations attempted and the result?   That may help to provide some insight on whether it isn't running or there is a problem interfering with it taking ownership of partitions?  The event source for the logs can be found here:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor/src/ProcessorEventSource.cs

Comment: @JesseSquire - Please suggest how to see processor logs?

Comment: I'd suggest investigating the EventListener in .NET, which would allow you to hook the EventSource.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlistener?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the AlwaysOn feature is used to keep your app loaded, particularly when it's not receiving any traffic.

However, I am aware of numerous instances of AppServices, across a number of Azure Regions, where the metrics were showing the instance count different to the number of instances deployed.  This was since yesterday.  I believe there have been underlying Azure issues.

In the Azure Portal, under the menu for your WebApp, you should be able to see the recent health of your WebApp within the 'Resource Health' section.

I would advise that you raise a ticket with Microsoft, just to be sure.

#### #azurefamily

Comment: I checked the 'Resource Health' of Web App and it was Available.