# Azure App Service shows 6 instances for Data In Metrics and showing 5 Instances for CPU Time metrics

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I am running 6 instances of my application on Azure App Service. **Data In** metrics shows 6 instances while CPU Time metrics shows 5 instances. I am confused.
Please suggest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please avoid asking duplicate question for the same problem. Instead, go back and edit your previous question and provide additional details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785982/all-instances-are-not-running-in-azure-app-service

Comment: @GauravMantri - Will take care next time. thanks.

Comment: @AlexAIT - yes it seems to be helpful